# What does "NATS" stand for?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I've started to work with Cloud Foundry and just noticed something: What does the acronym "**NATS**" stand for? I searched via Google, Cloud Foundry and their documentations, but didn't find anything which could possibly clear it up.

Answer (score 4):

**N**ot **A**nother **T**ibco **S**erver!

The developer also use to work at Tibco :-)

Answer (score 2):

Semi-officially, NATS stands for **N**eural **A**utonomic **T**ransport **S**ystem. Derek Collison (designer/architect of Cloud Foundry, creator of NATS and founder/CEO of Apcera) conceived NATS as a messaging platform that functions like a central nervous system.

Unofficially, many folks like to say it stands for what Ali Moghadam said :)

[disclaimer/source: I am NATS Product Manager at Apcera]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's a particular significant name. You could always ask in the VCAP google group;

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

Or even ask the author himself;

https://github.com/derekcollison/nats